# Using generated id from template in another function?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, polymer, shadow-dom

having a bit of trouble here. I need to play an audio file on-click of an image that I have. A bunch of images + their corrosponding audio files are set in my template (that works):

```
<template>
    <div layout horizontal wrap center center-justified class="asdf">
        <template repeat="{{s in carddata}}">
            <sound-card>
                <img src="{{s.imgurl}}" on-click="{{playaudio}}">
                <span>{{s.quote}}</span>
                <audio id="{{s.soundId}}" src="{{s.soundurl}}" controls preload="auto" autobuffer></audio>
            </sound-card>
        </template>
    </div>
</template>
```

I'm setting the audio element to `display: none` so when you click on the image it just plays the audio instead of the play button. So far, so good, but! All of my values for this template are stored in this array:

```
<script>
    Polymer('card-container', {
        carddata: [],

        ready: function() {
            this.carddata = [
                {imgurl: '../www/img/soundcard-imgs/img1.jpg', quote: 'What?', soundurl: '../www/card-sounds/sound1.m4a', soundId: 'sound1'},
                {imgurl: '../www/img/soundcard-imgs/img2.jpg', quote: 'Tickle tickle!', soundurl: '../www/card-sounds/sound2.m4a', soundId: 'sound2'}

            ];
        },

        playaudio: function() {
            var audioId = //need to get ID here somehow
            audioId.play();
        }
    });

</script>
```

As you can see, I need to get the `{{s.soundId}}` of that particular `<sound-card>` and pass it to the `playaudio` function in order to play the correct sound for the correct image. I've been searching but I can't find a way to get the id that is generated by the array data binding.

Any tips? Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just place the sound ID as an attribute of the image tag? And then it will be sent in the click event ( playaudio:function(event){...})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try event.target.templateInstance.model.s.soundId

Comment: This appears to be getting the correct soundId. Now to fix my audio playing function.. Thanks! :-) Very simple.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your code is within the context of the app so I made a few assumptions (hopefully good ones). Here is a codepen with a more generic solution for you.

[A Simple Podcast Example](http://codepen.io/Nevraeka/pen/YPJNWb?editors=101)

**Polymer Element Imports (combined for simplicity sake)**

```
<!-- In reference to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28978974/using-generated-id-from-template-in-another-function -->

<polymer-element name="sound-card" 
                 attributes="image url quote">
    <template>
        <style>
            :host div {
                margin-left: 1em;
            }

            :host img {
                margin-right: 1em;
            }

            :host h3 {
                display: block;
                white-space: wrap;
                font: bold 1.5em/1 Arial, san-serif; 
            }
        </style>
        <div layout horizontal>
            <img src="{{image}}" 
                 alt="Audio cover picture" 
                 on-click="{{playAudio}}">
            <section>
                <h3>{{quote}}</h3>
                <audio controls preload="auto" autobuffer> 
                    <source src="{{url}}" type="audio/mpeg">
                </audio>
            </section>
        </div>
    </template>

    <script>
     Polymer('sound-card', {

         playAudio: function() {
             this.shadowRoot.querySelector('audio').play();
         }

     });
</script>
</polymer-element>

<polymer-element name="play-list" 
             attributes="list">
    <template>
        <style>
            :host div {
                margin: 2em;
            }
            :host sound-card {
                margin-bottom: 1em;
            }
        </style>
        <div layout horizontal wrap center>
            <template repeat="{{sound in sounds}}">
                <sound-card image="{{sound.image}}" 
                            quote="{{sound.quote}}" 
                            url="{{sound.url}}">
                </sound-card>
            </template>
        </div>
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer('play-list', {

            listChanged: function(oldVal, newVal){
                this.sounds = JSON.parse(newVal);
            },

            ready: function(){
                this.sounds = JSON.parse(this.list);
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

**Main JS file**

```
var data = [
      {
        "image" : "http://static.libsyn.com/p/assets/7/d/2/e/7d2eff1d932bd82f/episode-34-icon-small.png",
        "quote" : "34: Tenon.io & Web Accessibility",
        "url" : "http://traffic.libsyn.com/thewebplatform/episode-34_tenon-and-web-accessibility.mp3"
      },
      {
        "image" : "http://static.libsyn.com/p/assets/2/e/0/c/2e0cacdeefe15ec0/episode-32-small.png",
        "quote" : "32: Microsoft Spartan & Internet Explorer",
        "url" : "http://traffic.libsyn.com/thewebplatform/episode-32_microsoft-spartan-and-internet-explorer.mp3"
      }
    ];

document.querySelector('play-list').setAttribute('list', JSON.stringify(data));
```